# `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null` with SSR in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here is my react page:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Outer = styled(motion.div)`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #232323;
`;

const Inner = styled(motion.div)`
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
`;

const Framer = () => (
  <Outer>
    <Inner>
      Hey
    </Inner>
  </Outer>
);

export default Framer;
```

This is located under the `/pages` folder in a next.js app.

With `<Inner>Hey</Inner>`, it all works fine, but change this to `<Inner />` and it consistently gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null` when rendering on the server.

This has been a consistent problem whilst I'm getting to grips with next.js. It's hampering my production.

Error is reproduced on next.js@9.2.0 and next.js@9.1.7

```
<Outer>
  <h1>Hey</h1>
  <Inner />
</Outer>
```

Tested with above and renders fine. It would seem next.js pages need a little bit of text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the google chrome extension [JSON Viewer Awesome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer-awesome/iemadiahhbebdklepanmkjenfdebfpfe?hl=en) seems to have fixed this.

Parses as JSON without text, but renders markup with text.

Answer (score 3):

This error can also easily happen when you create a `_document.js` file and forget to include there `NextScript` tag. Happened to me - so I better post it here.